# How many non-empty bins after $m$ tosses, if some of the bins already are non-empty?

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

I could not find a similar question already asked on math.stackexchange, and it is bugging me, so here we go.

In the standard balls and bins paradigm, $m$ balls are thrown into $n$ bin uniformly and independently at random. A standard result is that on average, $n \left( 1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{m} \right)$ bins will contain at least one ball.

Now suppose we throw $m$ balls into $n$ bins, still uniformly and independently at random, but this time, before the beginning of the process, *$k$ bins already contain one ball or more*. **How many bins, on average, will contain at least one ball at the end of the process?**

The standard result can be easily solved with indicator random variables on whether bin $j$ received at least one ball or not, but I have no idea how to use them here.

Or maybe with the inclusion-exclusion principle, but I did not manage to apply it here.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indicator variables seems to work just as they do in the original case.

Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for the $i^{th}$ bin (so it is $1$ iff the $i^{th}$ bin contains a ball) Then the probability that $X_i=1$ is $$P=\frac kn\times 1 +\frac {n-k}n\times \left(1-(1-\frac 1n)^m \right)$$

As before, the average you want is then just $nP$, so $$E=k+(n-k)\times \left(1-(1-\frac 1n)^m \right)=n-(n-k)\times \left(1-\frac 1n\right)^m$$

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize it was that straightforward.